# Apply style to spinner

Tags: android, spinner

[image]

I want to work with the spinner item.
I want the drop down to have the same width and height than the button.

How can I do this?

Finally i solved it using a listview into a alertdialog like this:

```
public void seleccionaTemporada(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder selector = new AlertDialog.Builder(SeleccionaTemporadaActivity.this);
        selector.setTitle("Temporadas");

        selector.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        selector.setAdapter(temporadas, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashBoardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("temporada", temporadas.getItem(which));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        selector.show();
    }

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_selecciona_temporada"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_balon"
        android:onClick="seleccionaTemporada"
        android:text="@string/seleccionarTemporada"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
```

For my needs it is the best solution i think. Sorry for my bad explanation before.

Comment: what layout are you using? adding your xml to the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Popup Window. And create your own Spinner Popup. 
Example Code below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_window, null);
        RelativeLayout layout1 = holder.relativeLayout_multiChoiceDropDown;

        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

        pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        pw.setTouchable(true);
        pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        pw.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        pw.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
                {
                    pw.dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    pw.setContentView(layout);
    pw.showAsDropDown(layout1, -5, 0);

    final ListView list = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dropDownList);
    Adapter_DropDown adapter = new Adapter_DropDown(parentActivity, items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

pop_up_window.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/PopUpView"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/qatool_basic_info_dropdown"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dropDownList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#000"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```